# logic to split revenue data by account if there are multiple data points

Tags: sql

First off SQL noob here so my question may not make sense.

Table 1 has the ID and Name (the table i want to add data too)
Table 2 is a big table with millions of data points that I need to pull revenue information from.

Table 2 also has dateid which i converted to month and year somehow I want to aggregate the month and year into a quarter year and this is how far I got. I really need to keep this script like below but just modified slightly.

So in the end I want to have revenue by product and by quarter. What am I missing?

Here is my script

```
select t1.nameid,
    t1.date_id,
      -- month
      period_idtoid(t1.date_id,DATEID,MONTHOFYEAR) as month,
      -- year
  period_idtoid(t1.date_id,DATEID,YEARID) as year,
SELECT t1.month,t1.year
   CASE 
    WHEN month in (1,2,3) and year = 2012 then 'Q1 2012'
    WHEN month in (4,5,6) and year = 2012 then 'Q2 2012'
    WHEN month in (7,8,9) and year = 2012 then 'Q3 2012'
    WHEN month in (10,11,12) and year = 2012 then 'Q4 2012'
    WHEN month in (1,2,3) and year = 2013 then 'Q1 2013'
    WHEN month in (4,5,6) and year = 2013 then 'Q2 2013'
    WHEN month in (7,8,9) and year = 2013 then 'Q3 2013'
    WHEN month in (10,11,12) and year = 2013 then 'Q4 2013'
    WHEN month in (1,2,3) and year = 2013 then 'Q1 2014'
    WHEN month in (4,5,6) and year = 2013 then 'Q2 2014'

   END AS 'Quarter'

    FROM 'Big table t1'


       sum(case when product_group = 'dog food' then revenue else 0 end) as dog_food_spend,
       sum(case when product_group = 'cat food' then revenue else 0 end) as cat_food_spend,
       sum(case when product_group = 'parrot food' then revenue else 0 end) as parrot_food_spend,

   from table 2 t1 join
     table 1 t2
     on t1.nameid = t2.nameid
group by 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: What RDBMS product are you using?

Comment: Are you saying that table1 doesn't actually hold anything of relevance, and that you want to select aggregated data FROM table2 INTO table1?

Comment: yes table 1 only has the IDs and Names. Table 2 has everything. I don't need everything but just need the data for Table 1 ids and name. Sorry if this doesnt make sense as I am new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming T-SQL and SQL Server and date_id is a SQL DateTime:

```
SELECT product_group, 
       sum(revenue) as revenue, 
       quarter + ' ' + convert(varchar(4), year)  as quarter
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         bt.product_group, 
         sum(isnull(bt.revenue, 0)) as revenue,  
         year(r.date_id) as year, 
         month(r.date_id) as month,
         case when month(r.date_id) in (1,2,3) then 'Q1'
              when month(r.date_id) in (4,5,6) then 'Q2'
              when month(r.date_id) in (7,8,9) then 'Q3'
         else 'Q4' end as quarter

     FROM Revenue r
     LEFT JOIN BigTable bt ON r.nameid = bt.nameid
     GROUP BY bt.product_group, year(r.date_id), month(r.date_id)
    ) a
GROUP BY product_group, 
         year,
         quarter
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably what you're looking for:

```
select    nameid,
          year,
          case 
            when month in (1,2,3)    then concat('Q1 ',year)
            when month in (4,5,6)    then concat('Q2 ',year)
            when month in (7,8,9)    then concat('Q3 ',year)
            when month in (10,11,12) then concat('Q4 ',year)
            end as qtr,
         sum(case when product_group = 'dog food' then revenue else 0 end) as dog_food_spend,
         sum(case when product_group = 'cat food' then revenue else 0 end) as cat_food_spend,
         sum(case when product_group = 'parrot food' then revenue else 0 end) as parrot_food_spend
from     table2
where    nameid in (select nameid from table1) 
group by nameid,
         year,
         case 
            when month in (1,2,3)    then concat('Q1 ',year)
            when month in (4,5,6)    then concat('Q2 ',year)
            when month in (7,8,9)    then concat('Q3 ',year)
            when month in (10,11,12) then concat('Q4 ',year)
            end
order by nameid, year
```

This runs the above for Q2 of 2014 only: (based on your comments)

```
select    nameid,
          year,
          case 
            when month in (1,2,3)    then concat('Q1 ',year)
            when month in (4,5,6)    then concat('Q2 ',year)
            when month in (7,8,9)    then concat('Q3 ',year)
            when month in (10,11,12) then concat('Q4 ',year)
            end as qtr,
         sum(case when product_group = 'dog food' then revenue else 0 end) as dog_food_spend,
         sum(case when product_group = 'cat food' then revenue else 0 end) as cat_food_spend,
         sum(case when product_group = 'parrot food' then revenue else 0 end) as parrot_food_spend
from     table2
where    nameid in (select nameid from table1) 
     and year = 2014
     and month in (4,5,6)
group by nameid,
         year,
         case 
            when month in (1,2,3)    then concat('Q1 ',year)
            when month in (4,5,6)    then concat('Q2 ',year)
            when month in (7,8,9)    then concat('Q3 ',year)
            when month in (10,11,12) then concat('Q4 ',year)
            end
order by nameid, year
```

**EDIT -**

The below may be closer to what you want, based on your comments:

```
select    nameid,
          year,
          product_group,
          sum(case when month in (1,2,3)    then revenue else 0 end) as q1
          sum(case when month in (4,5,6)    then revenue else 0 end) as q2
          sum(case when month in (7,8,9)    then revenue else 0 end) as q3
          sum(case when month in (10,11,12) then revenue else 0 end) as q4
from     table2
where    nameid in (select nameid from table1) 
group by nameid,
         year,
         product_group
order by nameid, year, product_group
```

Comment: @user3802773 I just added the case statement to the group by clause as I forgot the first time around; if you already tried the previous query please retry w/ my edit

Comment: thank you for the help I have rephrased my question on another post. How do I delete this question?

Comment: @user3802773 did the above work? if not did you get an error was the output not what you expected?

Comment: select t1.name_id,
   t1.date_id,
   -- month
   period_idtoid(t1.date_id,DATEID,MONTHOFYEAR) as month,
   -- year
   period_idtoid(t1.date_id,DATEID,YEARID) as year,  
   sum(case when product_group = 'dog food' then revenue else 0 end) as dog spend,
   sum(case when product_group = 'cat food' then revenue else 0 end) as cat spend,
   sum(case when product_group = 'parrot food' then revenue else 0 end) as parrot spend,
   from Big_Table t1 join My_table t2 on t1.name_id = t2.name_id
   group by 1,2

Comment: What's wrong with the current format? It currently shows name, month, year, quarter, dog revenue, cat revenue, parrot revenue. What result columns do you actually want? (please list or edit your question w/ the desired result columns)

Comment: @user3802773 is it just that you want the quarters as columns?

Comment: o sorry, I meant better format when i wrote the script on the comment so it would be easier to read for you. I dont need the month or year but want to aggregate the month and year columns into a qtr/year column like Q2 2014. thank you for the help really appreciate it. And sorry for the confusion as you can clearly see I am SQL noob

Comment: @user3802773 so product_group should not be split up into 3 amount columns then? Because that would give 12 column's worth of data which I can't imagine looking pretty. I'm thinking you want as rows: (nameid, year, product_group, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4), is that right?

Comment: So overall I want ID---Name---dog_spend---cat_spend---parrot--qrt_spend as columns if that makes sense. So the qrt spend will give me the spend by product for that qrt year

Comment: @user3802773 i just edited w/ what I think will give you what you want. You can't really put the year as a column because Q1/Q2/Q3/Q4 is constant but the year will change as time goes on, ie. if you had a report for 2013 to 2014, so that really should be its own column.

Comment: @user3802773 okay i will redo w/ those columns

Comment: @user3802773 actually, the very first query I gave you has those columns as output

Comment: ok lets just make this easier. What if I want to just have spend by quarter for q2 2014 when given month and year. Also is there a way to keep it kind of like the format in the original query? What I mean is how do I modify my original query from the top to breakdown the spend by quarter for 2014

Comment: add to the where clause "and year = 2014 and month in (4,5,6)"

Comment: Where you I put the where clause? and does it look like this? WHERE month in (4,5,6) and year = 2014 then 'Q2 2014'

Comment: thank you for helping out a noob I am really testing your patience haha

Comment: also bear in mind that I was only given a dateid from table2 and some how converted it to month and year. So I really need to keep it like the format in the question

Comment: ok got it thanks! but now the schema shows month 4,5,6 how to i aggregate those into one column?

Comment: I just removed the month column in my edit. The amounts for each quarter will appear in the sum_rev columns. The quarters are listed as rows, otherwise you would have 12 columns (ie. Q1 for cats, Q1 for dogs, Q1 for parrots, Q2 for cats..... etc.) The result would be a mile wide if you did that, I can't see that being what you want

Comment: select t1.name_id,
    t1.date_id,
      -- month
      period_idtoid(t1.date_id,DATEID,MONTHOFYEAR) as month,
      -- year
  period_idtoid(t1.date_id,DATEID,YEARID) as year,

          sum(case when product_group = 'dog food' then revenue else 0 end) as dog_spend,
          sum(case when product_group = 'cat food' then revenue else 0 end) as cat_spend,
          sum(case when product_group = 'parrot food' then revenue else 0 end) as parrot_spend,
          
   from big_table t1 join
     my_table t2
     on t1.name_id = t2.name_id
     WHERE month in (4,5,6) 
     and year = 2014
group by ??

Comment: This is the script. My question is how do i aggregate the column spend by q2 2014

Comment: I try the scripts you had but they do not work. I need to keep it the format in like in the comment above in order for it to work for some reason

Comment: @user3802773 it's too unclear what you want, if you post a sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/ with some example data and draw out what you want I'll revisit it, but based on the columns you wanted I can't see why the first query wouldn't work

Comment: right now i just want to keep it simple as you can tell i am not to versed in SQL. From the script I wrote on 5 comments above how do I make it into q2 2014 as it of now it gives me months 4,5,6 on 1 column and year 2014 on another. I just want to tally them up so that I will have only 1 id with spend on each category for where function i created. Thank you for the assistance

Comment: I don't even see how the query you posted manages to run without an error; it uses aggregate functions but does not even have a group by clause

Comment: ran out of space in comment

Comment: The first query I posted will have one row per quarter, with the sum by category as columns. I really doubt you actually want to have the quarters as columns because it would result in you having 12 columns (4x3 , there are 4 quarters, 3 categories)

Comment: this would work but I was only given a dateid. I converted the dateid and it gave me month and year columns. I really need to keep this in the syntax. select t1.nameid,
    t1.date_id,
      -- month
      period_idtoid(t1.date_id,DATEID,MONTHOFYEAR) as month,
      -- year
  period_idtoid(t1.date_id,DATEID,YEARID) as year,

Comment: it would say month not in field list

Answer (score 0):

When your main data table contains millions of rows you will definitely want to do a pre-aggregation:

```
create table #t (
     Quarter         varchar(7)
    ,ProductGroup    varchar(20)
    ,Amount          money
);

insert #t(Quarter,ProductGroup,Amount)
select
   CASE 
     when month between  1 and  3 then 'Q1 '
     when month between  4 and  6 then 'Q2 '
     when month between  7 and  9 then 'Q3 '
     when month between 10 and 12 then 'Q4 '
   end + cast(year as char(4))
   as Quarter,
   ProductGroup,
   sum(Amount) as Amount
from [Big Table]
group by
   CASE 
     when month between  1 and  3 then 'Q1 '
     when month between  4 and  6 then 'Q2 '
     when month between  7 and  9 then 'Q3 '
     when month between 10 and 12 then 'Q4 '
   end + cast(year as char(4))
   as Quarter,
   ProductGroup;

select
    PoductGroup
    ,"Q1 2012","Q2 2012","Q3 2012","Q4 2012"
    ,"Q1 2013","Q2 2013","Q3 2013","Q4 2013"
    ,"Q1 2014","Q2 2014","Q3 2014","Q4 2014"
from #t
pivot (sum(Amount) for Quarter in ("Q1 2012","Q2 2012","Q3 2012","Q4 2012"
                                  ,"Q1 2013","Q2 2013","Q3 2013","Q4 2013"
                                  ,"Q1 2014","Q2 2014","Q3 2014","Q4 2014")
group by ProductGroup;

drop table #t;
```

Comment: what does the #t and the #t1 mean?

Comment: @user3802773: #t1 is supposed to be #t; I have corrected. The '#' in #t marks it has a temporary table (temporary to the specific connection) that is automatically removed when the connection closes and exists in tempdb.